# html links not working (using base href)

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, radix

hi there I am using this tag:

```
<base href="http://awebsite.ca/” target=" />
```

in association with this tag:

```
<a href=“main_page/mainpage.html”><br><b>main</b></br></a>
```

and getting this in the browser:

```
http://awebsite.ca/â€œmain_page/mainpage.htmlâ€%C2%9D
```

Comment: you are using the wrong `"` sign

Answer (score 5):

You have to quote attribute values with `"` (QUOTATION MARK) or `'` (APOSTROPHE), not `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and `”` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK).

This type of error is typically caused by writing code using a word processor (such as Microsoft Word or Apple Pages) with automatic replacement of quotes with typographic quotes (aka Smart Quotes) enabled. Try using a text editor (such as Visual Studio Code, Sublime Text, Komodo Edit, Emacs, or Vim) instead.

The other common cause for this error is copy/pasting code from a website where the author has let a WordProcess CMS or similar mangle their input in the same way as a word processor. Check code you are copy/pasting carefully.